# Sort Javascript array based on a substring in the array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, substr

```
var arr = ["This is three", "This is four", "This is one", "This is two", ...];
```

If I have an array like the one shown above, and I need to sort the array based on the substring value in the strings - i.e one, two, three.., 
What is the best approach to the problem?

My final result should be

```
var sortedArr = ["This is one", "This is two", "This is three", "This is four", ...];
```

Comment: maybe you post some of your attempts for solving the problem.

Comment: arr.sort() sorts in alphabetical order. That doesn't help. The substings are numerical like one, two, three etc. Using sort function on the substrings won't sort it in the required order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses an array with the numbers and looks in the string for the number word and returns the index for sorting.

For bigger arrays, I suggest to use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
var sortedArr = ["This is four", "This is two", "This is one", "This is three"];

sortedArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getNumber(s) {
        var index = -1;
        ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'].some(function (c, i) {
            if (~s.indexOf(c)) {
                index = i;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return index;
    }
    return getNumber(a) - getNumber(b);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Edit:

> `~` is a [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It is perfect for use with indexOf(), because `indexOf` returns if found the index `0 ... n` and if not `-1`:
>
> ```
> value  ~value   boolean
>  -1  =>   0  =>  false
>   0  =>  -1  =>  true
>   1  =>  -2  =>  true
>   2  =>  -3  =>  true
>   and so on
> ```

Comment: could you explain how does this notation `~s` work? Thanks

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz  thanks, I was able to use the logic in my code and it worked like a charm. some() was new to me. Thanks, accepting your answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz, thanks for interesting alternative with `NOT Bitwise` operator. I'll bear it in mind